# Elasticsearch analyzer couldn't found Exception

Tags: exception, elasticsearch, analyzer

I created my index with the settings of my analyzer and it shows my analyzer settings when I call the index properties. When I try to use index something with the analyzer it throws an exception named " analyzer couldn't found". Here is my analyzer settings;

```
"settings":{
    "index":{
        "settings":{
            "analysis":{
                "filter":{
                    "turkce_lowercase":{
                        "type":"lowercase",
                        "language":"turkish"},
                    "turkce_stop":{
                        "type":"stop",
                        "stopwords_path":"/home/power/Documents/stop_words.txt"}
                        },
                "analyzer":{
                    "turkce":{
                        "filter":["turkce_lowercase","turkce_stop"],
                        "tokenizer":"standard_tokenizer"}
                        },
                "tokenizer":{
                    "standard_tokenizer":{
                        "type":"standard",
                        "max_token_length":"900"}
                        }
                        }
                    }
             }
            }
```

Comment: Can you show the query you're trying to send?

Comment: I don't send any query when I post
/_analyze?analyzer=turkce it says analyzer not found but in the settings of index I see my analyzer.

Comment: Can you try to add `"type": "custom"`in your `turkce` analyzer (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html))?

Comment: let me try. I'll update with the result.

Comment: It worked. I assume that it was searching my anaylzer as a standart analyzer and threw the exception. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

In your [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html), you simply need to add `"type": "custom"` to denote that your analyzer is a custom analyzer and not a standard one.

```
  "analyzer": {
    "turkce": {
      "type": "custom",            <----- add this
      "filter": [
        "turkce_lowercase",
        "turkce_stop"
      ],
      "tokenizer": "standard_tokenizer"
    }
  }
```